# ggplot make range of color scale a subset of the range of the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-raster

I'm trying to modify the scale of a heatmap with `geom_raster` such that the color change occurs over a subset of the data and anything outside that subset doesn't get any more or less colorful.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(reshape2)

q <- letters[1:5]
w <- rev(letters)[1:5]
x1 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x2 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x3 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x4 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x5 <- rnorm(5, 10, 1)

test.df <- melt(data.frame(q,w,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5))

ggplot(test.df, aes(q,variable,fill=value))+geom_raster()+scale_fill_viridis()
```

If you run that, you get this heatmap:

[image: heatmap].

The top row is "hogging" some of the color range. Since the vast majority of the data is between -2 and 2, I'd like to make it so that the color scale change occurs over that range, and anything outside of it is just yellow or purple. To me, anything over 2 should just be "very high" and anything under -2 should be "very low", but the numbers between -2 and 2 are what I want to see.

I don't think `cut` is what I want because then I need to supply a bunch of colors, and I don't want to remove any data or change any data over some value to some maximum or anything like that. Setting limits in the `scale_viridis` command helps but removes data outside the limits.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function such as `dplyr::case_when` to truncate the values at your endpoints. Then if you want, you can set labels on the legend accordingly. Note that I typed the labels manually in order to do `"<= -2"` and `">= 2"`; not sure if this would suffice, or if you may need something more dynamic.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1234)
q <- letters[1:5]
w <- rev(letters)[1:5]
x1 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x2 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x3 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x4 <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
x5 <- rnorm(5, 10, 1)

test.df <- melt(data.frame(q,w,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)) %>%
  mutate(val_trimmed = case_when(
    value > 2 ~ 2,
    value < -2 ~ -2,
    T ~ value
  )) 

ggplot(test.df, aes(x = q, y = variable, fill = val_trimmed)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis(labels = c("<= -2", "-1", "0", "1", ">= 2"), breaks = -2:2) +
  labs(caption = "Note: values truncated above 2 and below -2")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This one does work in fact, though I'm curious as to why the other one seems to not.

Comment: I set the data to only go between -2 and 2, and then set the breaks of the fill accordingly. Values below -2 are set to -2, and likewise for positive 2. That's to account for the broad spread of data

Answer (score 3):

If the values only exceed the scale at one end (looks to be the case with your data, you have values greater than 2, but not less than -2) you can change values that exceed your maximum to `NA` in your dataframe and then use the `na.value =` option in `scale_fill_viridis()` to make all of the NA values a certain color.

```
#change values greater than 2 to NA
test.df$value <- ifelse(test.df$value <= 2, test.df$value, NA)

ggplot(test.df, aes(q, variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis(na.value = "yellow", #make NAs (values > 2) yellow
                     limits = c(-2,2), #define limits of scale
                     labels = c(as.character(-2:1), ">= 2"), breaks = -2:2)
```

[image]

This solution is less flexible than the other answers, as it won't work if you have values that exceed your range on the high and low end of the scale, but it's an easy, concise way to do this if you only have outliers on one end of the scale.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scale_fill_gradientn` to have full control on your color gradient. The code below will assign different colors across `[-2, 2]` but will keep the edge colors consistent beyond these values. Please try to set seed in your questions using `set.seed` for reproducibility.

```
ggplot(test.df, aes(q, variable, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = c("blue", "blue", "red", "red"),
    values = c(-999, -2, 2, 999)
  )
```

Simply increase the number of colors and values to extend your color gradient.

Comment: This seems like it should work but mostly it just turns my heatmap a purpleish color. [link](http://tinypic.com/r/317jj9x/9) The top plot is of my actual data, and the second is the same code but with your scale_gradient_n() code added to it.

Comment: Have you run this with the OP's data? There's barely any difference between shades in the fills, all the tiles come out basically the same reddish-pink